# href not working on localhost: maybe wrong directory?

Tags: java, html, httpserver

I'm working with Java and Eclipse and I'm using HttpServer. I need to write a simple server and a couple of webpages.
This is my project directory:

```
Demo
|
--bin
|
|
--doc
|   |
|   --js
|   --index.html
|   --ciao.html
|
--src
    |
    --server
        |
        --RootHandler.java
```

When I connect to localhost at the right port, a `RootHandler` in Java gives me the `index.html` file that is my homepage, and everything is fine:

```
public void handle(HttpExchange arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (arg0.getRequestURI().getPath().equals("/")) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("");
        try {
            File f = new File("./doc/index.html");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        arg0.sendResponseHeaders(200, text.length());

        OutputStream os = (OutputStream) arg0.getResponseBody();
        os.write(text.toString().getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I surf on my homepage and I want to change page or include some Javascript. If in `index.html` I simply use an anchor tag like this:

`<a href="ciao.html">Ciao</a>`

it doesn't work. The page loads forever and the request of the new `ciao.html` remains "pending". Note that the new page is in the same directory of `index.html`.

I tried other paths like:

```
/ciao.html
./ciao.html
/doc/ciao.html
doc/ciao.html
```

and many others but no one worked. What am I missing? Which is the root directory of my website?

Obviously the problem also occurs when I would like to include a script because this doesn't work, and its variations don't work either:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: It seems like, You serve the index.html via a Servlet, but you are trying to bypass the servlet when requesting the ciao.html

Comment: Have you set up a way for your server to serve ciao.html? There isn't one in the code you provided

Comment: @robinsax If I created a context to return the ciao.html file there would not be any problems, BUT if the ciao.html file included script or css it would not work. For this reason I wonder if there are any issues at the directory level, perhaps the root of my website is not what I think